# angular spa and seo deprecating ajax crawling scheme

Tags: angularjs, seo, single-page-application

I'm about to build a frontend for an ecommerce website that interact with a soap webservice built in java. I would like to use angularjs because I've some experience with it, but so far I've just make some spa web application where seo was not necessary.

I have some doubts. I found a lot of resources about this arguments, but they are all older than this article from google:

1. [deprecating our ajax crawling scheme](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

The main doubts are about:

1. urls
2. allow bot to access js and css files
3. pre rendered contents

**URLs**

> Since the assumptions for our 2009 proposal are no longer valid, we recommend following the principles of progressive enhancement. For example, you can use the History API pushState() to ensure accessibility for a wider range of browsers (and our systems).

As I understood _escaped_fragment_ must be avoided at all. So, for the urls, I can just use #! or also better:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

**BOT**

> To reflect this improvement, we recently updated our technical Webmaster Guidelines to recommend against disallowing Googlebot from crawling your site's CSS or JS files.

I also need to allow googlebot to access all js and css files putting this on robot.txt:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: .js
Allow: .css
```

**CONTENTS**

> Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers.

...

> A: In general, websites shouldn't pre-render pages only for Google -- we expect that you might pre-render pages for performance benefits for users and that you would follow progressive enhancement guidelines. If you pre-render pages, make sure that the content served to Googlebot matches the user's experience, both how it looks and how it interacts.

The pages might or must be pre-rendered?

Am I totally wrong about the other points?